# How to display 2 cards in a row in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, mobile-website

This is my [glitch](https://tfs-service.glitch.me/).Here I can see 3 cards in a row for desktops and 2 card per row in a tablet and 1 card for mobile devices. I wanted it to make 2 cards per row in mobile.(Means I want my cards to be resized and display 2 cards in a row in mobile devices).How can I achieve it. Here is my complete glitch [code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tfs-service).

This is a css, what I tried in media query for responsiveness.

```css
/*** Responsive ***/
@media(max-width: 991px)
{
    .wrapper{
        padding: 25px;
    }
    .wrapper h1{
        font-size: 2.5em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .content-box{
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .card{
        min-width:300px;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mre] of your issue belong directly into your question, please do not just dump it onto external platforms.

Comment: Please Add Your code ;-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarioG8 , Please check my question, I have updated it.

Comment: @CBroe , Sorry I'm new to this platform,  Thanks for your suggestion. I will improve it.

Comment: @RamyaYadav Update html too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

why is your container flex-direction column on media query? should have been row.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @rikesh shreshtha , your solution  fixed responsiveness  in tablet devices.